# Difference between Span and div tags unless styling

Tags: html

I know there are lots of documents on span and div but I really understood how it happens with styling part. Unless styling do we have anything change with span and div tags in HTML where the behaviour of the application changes a lot?

Answer (score 0):

span element is in-line and usually used for a small chunk of HTML inside a line like inside the

tag where as  is used for block-line. div tag also uses line-break before and after  tag.

Answer (score 0):

span element is inline element it means it only takes the minimum or required space for content
[see the output of span element(inline level)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JpSl.png)

while div element takes full space (100%) because it is block level element
[output of div element (block level)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHsK2.png)